# AJAX Codeigniter getting data for modal

Tags: javascript, ajax, codeigniter, post, get

I've been using CodeIgniter for a little while, and I'm trying to get a modal to work. I'm using bootstrap library so the model itself is rather simple to show. The thing is I'm trying to load it with dynamic information from a database using ajax. But I can't seem to trigger it. My script doesn't do anything, I've been trying for quite a while now.

```
 function fun(control){
   $.ajax({
        url:'<?=base_url()?>admin/proveedores/userDetails/'+control.id,
        method: 'post',
        data: {uid: control.id},
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(response){
         var len = response.length;

         if(len > 0){
          // Read values
          var uname = response[0].razon_social;
          var name = response[0].cuit;
          var email = response[0].rubro;

          $('#suname').text(uname);
          $('#sname').text(name);
          $('#semail').text(email);
 }
</script>
```

The HTML PART

```
<div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <div >
            Username : <span id='suname'></span><br/>
            Name : <span id='sname'></span><br/>
            Email : <span id='semail'></span><br/>
           </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
```

The function call

```
<tr id="<?= $e['id'] ?>" onclick="fun(this)" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" >
```

The Controller

```
public function userDetails($cid){
        // POST data
        //  $postData = $this->input->post();

          // get data
          $data = $this->model_proveedores->get($cid);

          echo json_encode($data);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it will helpful for you. 
Please keep the modal content inside a div with id **myModal** and call ajax within the modal show action.

**The Modal**

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        // your modal content
    </div>
</div>
```

**The Call Button**

```
  <tr data-id="<?= $e['id'] ?>" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
```

---

**The Script**

```
var modal = $("#myModal");
modal.on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
    var button = $(event.relatedTarget);
    var id      = button.data('id'); 

    $.ajax({
        url      : '<?= base_url() ?>admin/proveedores/userDetails/'+id,
        type     : 'post',
        dataType : 'json',
        data     : { uid: id},
        success  : function(response)
        {
            var len = response.length;

            if(len > 0){
                // Read values
                var uname = response[0].razon_social;
                var name = response[0].cuit;
                var email = response[0].rubro;

                $('#suname').text(uname);
                $('#sname').text(name);
                $('#semail').text(email);
            }
        },
        error    : function(xhr)
        {
            console.log(xhr)
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: It keeps giving the same output, a modal with the content of the modal div, but without any of the data it should've broght from the ajax function. I think it's not event triggering it.

Comment: 1. If you want to stop triggering the then you can set a condition in button 

**<tr data-id="<?= $e['id'] ?>" <?= (!empty($e['id']):("data-toggle='modal' data-target='#myModal'"):null) ?>>**

2. Another way to hide modal while data not found 

 **if(len > 0)
 {
  // read value
 } 
 else 
 { 
  modal.modal('hide'); 
     // if no data found
 }**

Answer (score 0):

Your response is JSON encoded. You must decode that before using it as an object.

```
response=JSON.parse(response);
```

Comment: I think it's not even calling the ajax function.